# paired bluetooth device always return hashset

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue with Blueetooth API,
I am trying to get the list of of bonded device with which one of our SDK will connect and continue card processing , problem we are facing is getBonded method of BTAdapter return unmodifiable hashset , is there any way i can change the sequence so that our 3rd part sdk connects to my desired device ?

Comment: Are you trying to add a device to the set?  It sounds like you're supposed to use some other approach for adding a new device...

Comment: I am not trying to add new devices. I am trying to retrive paired devices and framework returns set<BluetoothDevice> and it is unmodifiable.. any idea ?

Comment: How is that not what you want?  You get a set of the paired devices.  Why does it matter that it is unmodifiable?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java),

If you call the method "getBondedDevices" in BluetoothAdapter,
it Returns:

> unmodifiable set of BluetoothDevice, or null on error

If you want to change the sequence of the BondedDevices object, use ArrayList.

Here is the sample code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> myBondedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// change the set of the Bluetooth devices to modifiable object
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> myBondedDevices2 = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
for (BluetoothDevice device: myBondedDevices){
    myBondedDevices2.add(device);
}
```